# Android: Recorded Video is not saved in Gallery

Tags: android

I 'm creating the application to record the video and to display the recorded video. I followed http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html.
but video is started to record, and i stopped the recording. but it is not displayed in Gallery. Where it will be...? or anything i missed to save the recorded video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) example that Android Developers supply on their Dev Guides.